# Why parameterize is extremely slow the first time it is executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code that basically times the execution time for parameterize:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'

for x in 0..10
  ss = Array.new(1000, "Book Author Title")
  st = Time.now
  ss = ss.map {|s| s.parameterize}
  et = Time.now
  p "parameterize 1000 simple strings takes #{'%.4f' % ((et - st)*1000)} milliseconds"
end
# p ss
```

However I got the output, like:

```
"parameterize 1000 simple strings takes 219.5780 milliseconds"
"parameterize 1000 simple strings takes 74.3870 milliseconds"
"parameterize 1000 simple strings takes 73.9830 milliseconds"
"parameterize 1000 simple strings takes 76.3160 milliseconds"
"parameterize 1000 simple strings takes 65.7620 milliseconds"
"parameterize 1000 simple strings takes 78.5280 milliseconds"
"parameterize 1000 simple strings takes 89.2950 milliseconds"
"parameterize 1000 simple strings takes 90.6750 milliseconds"
"parameterize 1000 simple strings takes 93.8500 milliseconds"
"parameterize 1000 simple strings takes 74.2330 milliseconds"
"parameterize 1000 simple strings takes 86.2160 milliseconds"
```

The first time it is executed cost so much more than the following, I want to understand why is that.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What if you do one string, then 1000 several times? There may be a startup penalty calling `parameterize` the first time.

Comment: `parameterize` [calls `transliterate`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/transliterate.rb#L94), which [in turn calls](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/transliterate.rb#L64) `I18n.transliterate`. Maybe something in I18n is causing the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: 
   The first invocation of ActiveSupport::Inflector#parametrize ends up loading unicode database [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.3/activesupport/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb#L340). This adds 70 plus milliseconds overhead, and the main reason why first invocation was slower.

**Long Answer:**
The first invocation of `"Book Author Title”.parametrize` is slow due to following reasons:

1. Loading the unicode database plus normalize takes 70 plus
   milliseconds
2. I18n.transliterate("Book Author Title") on first invocation translates in 10-15 milliseconds and cache the response. Subsequent calls return cached value, which takes 0.002 milliseconds.

Below are the sequence of calls that load unicode database:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.parametrize ->
 ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate ->
  ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Unicode.normalize ->
   https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.3/activesupport/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb#L340
```

Try the below snippet to verify.

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
def benchmark_normalize(s)
  st = Time.now
  ts = ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Unicode.normalize(s, :c)
  et = Time.now
  p "takes #{'%.4f' % ((et - st)*1000)} milliseconds"
end
benchmark_normalize("Book Author Title")
```